# Calling a Javascript in a page disables the Ajax controls

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I have an asp.net application and in Gridview i'm calling a Javascript to print a document as HTML. The application runs fine in IE. But, When i try it from google chrome it disables the ajax controls and shows the hidden panels and div's used for ModalPopup controls.

Here is the javascript im using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CallPrintResume() {
        var prtContent = document.getElementById('<%= hdnPrintResumeData.ClientID %>');
          var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
          WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.value);
          WinPrint.document.close();
          WinPrint.focus();
          WinPrint.print();
          WinPrint.close();
          prtContent.value = "";

    }
</script>
```

I'm calling this code from server side in C# like this.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "CallPrintResume();", true);
```

When I click on the button it will call the above method and a dialog window will appear for Printing the document.

The entire thing is inside an UpdatePanel and it works fine in Internet Explorer without disabling any of the controls.

When i try from Chrome, it will just start to show the controls which are associated with ModalPopup extenders and page gets stuck. Then, you must have to refresh the entire page to run again.

I tried this with and without updatepanel. In both it works fine with IE but not in Chrome. Do anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Open the browser console in Chrome by reply dressing F12. There should be a JavaScript error. Please tell us what the error message is and even what the stack trace is if one is provided.

Comment: document.write clears all document dont use it

Comment: So instead of document.write what can we use?